# Pex not satisfying code contract

Tags: code-contracts, pex, pex-and-moles

I'm trying to wrote a pex test, and I noticed that it always was feeding a false value as one of the params that I wanted. My test looked like this (simplified: there are/were more params, but otherwise no different):

```
[PexMethod]
public void TestCtor(bool value)
{
    ArbitraryType myType = new ArbitraryType(value);
}
```

I wanted to test a scenario where I would have pex do the exploration, ensuring that `value` would be true. I made another test that looked like this:

```
[PexMethod]
public void TestCtor(bool value)
{
    Contract.Requires(value == true);

    ArbitraryType myType = new ArbitraryType(value);
}
```

But when I have Pex explore that, it still spits in false to `value` and the test it generates "passes". If I put a line after the requirement saying `Contract.Assert(!value);` It'll create another test and pass true for `value` to fail the assertion.

The question is, why isn't Pex satisfying the code contract?

Comment: I'm assuming that you have enabled Contract checking at Runtime under Tools -> Options -> Code Contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what Pex is going to do with Contracts in the test methods, but I can't  see it being a Good Thing :)

If you want Pex to do this, the correct thing to do is use `PexAssume.IsTrue(value)`.